# Anki does not translate latex code correctly as soon as I format the input as cloze

Tags: anki

For other examples (see picture) it works fine. I can't see the difference between the first and second formula, maybe a bug? It even shows up correctly above, but when reviewed it seems to have some sort of problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cloze texts in Anki are marked with the syntax "{{c1:: foo }}", you have to take care to separate all double closed curly brackets "}}" with a space in your latex code. Otherwise the app thinks the cloze ends there, which makes the following latex code obsolete.

> \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}}{\sqrt[n]{c}}

to

> \frac{\sqrt[n]{a} }{\sqrt[n]{c} }